# Strange memory usage in while(1) vs. for(;;)

Tags: php, performance, execution-time

I have the 2 following codes.

1:

```
$i = 0;
while(1)
{
    $i++;

    echo "big text for memory usage ";
    if ( $i == 50000 )
    break;
}

echo "<br />" . memory_get_usage();
```

It echoes every time : `1626464`

2:

```
$i = 0;
for(;;)
{
    $i++;

    echo "big text for memory usage ";
    if ( $i == 50000 )
    break;
}

echo "<br />" . memory_get_usage();
```

It echoes every time : `1626656`

Can anybody exaplain this difference between the 2 different memory usages? Even if they are so small...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an implementation detail. With the for loop, PHP probably uses some space to store three pointers, one for the for intialization, one for the incrementation, and one for the stop condition. If you're on a 64-bit system, then this accounts for the `64 * 3 = 192` extra bits you're seeing. Of course, it's hard to tell if I'm right without looking at the actual code.

Comment: Yes this is a 64bit system. I think you are correct and the extra 192 bits come from here. Thank you, it was just a curiosity !

Answer (score 4):

The amount of memory difference you're seeing is very negligible and shouldn't be a concern. The way the two loops are compiled should not affect memory usage, but they may affect runtime speed (still negligible though).

For instance:
`while(1)`: This will cause the compiler to check if `1` is true; if it isn't, it will jump to the end of your loop - if it is, it will process the loop's contents.

`for(;;)`: A standard `for`-loop does three things. It defines an iterator, which you skip, checks if the iterator meets a condition, which you also skip, executes the body content, and then increments the iterator and jumps back to the condition-check. The jumps are all still in-place, but your code doesn't do anything at each (hence the "endless loop" - until you manually break, of course).

As a pure guess for a potential answer as-to-why the `for`-loop has a very slight raise in memory could be *because* of the way it's supposed to work - with a defined/managed iterator. PHP could pre-allocate extra space, if very small, to accomodate for this iterator and garbage collection even if you're not using it.

Comment: Yes, I know what they do, just wanted to know where the extra 192 bits came from and I think Cygal gave me the answer.